# Selecting a MOSFET Shield

Tags: mosfet

Im building an electrical system for my EBike.  My bike has 2 power sources, one is the 48 volt battery, the other is a 12 power converter coming off the battery pack.  I need an arduino shield that has 4 switching channels.  2 that can take in the 48 volt and switch it on and off, and two that can take in the 12 volt and switch it on and off.  Something that can take the 12 volt to power the arduino uno would be nice but I can find a chip to do that if necessary.

Since these are lights, normally off would be more more efficient but with the power consumption we are talking about, i can probably run the battery all day to the point of dry and the fets eat all of 50 feet worth of power staying closed.

Does anyone know of anything like that?  I found several shields out there like [this](http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/Brick-4ChannelPowerFetSwitch) but all of them seem to be setup to take 1 voltage input and switch it between the 4 or 6 fets on the board, not different voltages per fet and since I'm a programmer, not an EE so I have trouble reading the schematics.

Because my grounds have to be tied, its easier to switch the positive on and off than the negative.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own. Buy a protoshield and 4 fets (and a few resistors).

You can also use the shield you linked to, by not using the `+` terminals on the board. Just connect the `+` of the lights directly to the battery and only the `-` of the light to the shield.

The Uno can be powered by up-to 20V, so you can connect it directly to the battery.